# Passing multiple results back in URL from view to controller with MVC from wrapped selectViewList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on populating two dropdown lists in the view with a single submit button that will pass through the selections. However the parameters in the url are getting returned as null when accessed through the method though i can see it populated in the string:

Expected URL:
http://localhost:8080/store/DisplaySelection?firstId=item1&secondId=item+2

But the URL I'm getting is:
http://localhost:8080/store/DisplaySelection?firstList.firstId=item+1&secondList.secondId=item+2

The controller method that is accessed when the submit button looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult DisplaySelection(string CatId, string BrandId)
    {
        ViewBag.catId = CatId;
        ViewBag.brandId = BrandId;
        return View(ViewBag);
    }
```

The change of the name is due to when I'm passing the data held in the dropdown to the view, since i have two lists of data, I have a wrapped class so i have to select he correct list to display before i can use the data.

And example would be:

```
public class SecondDropDownViewModel
{
    public string secondId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> List { get; set; }
    public static List<SelectListItem> BuildSecondList(IEnumerable<Dtos.Second> second)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "item 1", Value = "itemd 1"
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "item 2", Value = "itemd 2"
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "item 3", Value = "itemd 3"

        return items;
    }
}

public class FirstDropDownViewModel
{
    public string firstId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> List { get; set; }
    public static List<SelectListItem> BuildFirstList(IEnumerable<Dtos.First> first)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "item 1", Value = "itemd 1"
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "item 2", Value = "itemd 2"
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "item 3", Value = "itemd 3"

        return items;
    }
}

public class DropDownViewModel
{
    public FirstDropDownViewModel firstList { get; set; }
    public BrandDropDownViewModel secondist { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ DropDownViewModel vm = new DropDownViewModel();

        vm.firstList = new FirstDropDownViewModel
        {
            List = FirstDropDownViewModel.BuildFirstList()

        };
        vm.secondList = new SecondDropDownViewModel
        {
            List = SecondDropDownViewModel.BuildSecondList()
        };
        return View(vm); }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DisplaySelection", "store", FormMethod.Get)){
<fieldset>
        Grade Type
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.firstList.CatId, Model.firsList.List, "--Select Category--")
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.secondList.BrandId, Model.secondList.List, "--Select Brands--")
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Generate your view model correctly with properties `string CatId` and string `BrandId` for bind to and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CatList` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BrandList` (and never attempt to change the name attribute unless you want to screw up your app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name that is generated as part of your form does not have a corresponding property to bind to in the action where you accept the form input. Try the following instead, where you add a parameter to the `DropDownListFor` to specify the name:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.firstList.firstId, Model.firstList.List, "--Select Category--", new {Name= "CatId" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.secondist.secondId, Model.secondist.List, "--Select Brands--", new {Name= "BrandId" })
```

If you inspect the HTML of the generated form (press F12) you'll see that the form name of the dropdown is something like `object_propertyname`. Your signature on the action does not have a parameter that matches that name, nor does it have a parameter with an object that has a property of that name. Either would work, as would changing the name above.

Also, consider favoring `POST` over `GET` if the action you are writing will cause any change on the server.